# Consistent Testing error (Rspec-core 2.14.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, integration-testing, rspec-rails

I'm going through Mhartl's tutorial and I'm sporadically getting this error when I run tests in the sublime text 2 console. If I use bundle exec rspec/rspec in the the terminal it works fine, but it's not the case when call shortcut commands in sublime text to run tests. I don't know if it makes a difference but I'm also running guard

```
Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.14.5, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.13.1. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I tried searching stack overflow for solutions and tried bundle exec rake db:migrate(I normally don't specify bundle exec) as well as bundle exec rake test:prepare. Neither of which work.

I'd appreciate not only an answer to the problem but perhaps a more in-depth answer of when to use rake db:migrate and rake test:prepare. I know their main uses, but there are perhaps some less obvious times where i would need to run it. SPecifically, for this problem I would have thought rake test:prepare would be relevant and I'm still not sure what effect rake db:migrate has on the testing suite/rspec part of the application

Comment: *Note, I don't want to update and I want to use rspec-core 2.13.1. WHen I call gemlist I see both available. How would I remove only one of them (2.14.1)?

Comment: You need to find out what's pulling in 2.14.1. Have you checked your `Gemfile.lock` file?

Comment: yes, there doesn't seem to be an instance of 2.14.1  `rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer part of your question, you can delete unused gems through `bundle clean`, although when I've had multiple versions of gems, I've found that I had to use `bundle clean --force` which may mean that I had "system gems" coming into play, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/10190608/1008891.