# Bundle install not running properly, gem corrupted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While running the bundle install, it stops installing when it reaches the installation of the byebug gem. Saying, the gem maybe corrupt. I have tried uninstalling the ruby application and also tried updating my ruby and also my rails version

Comment: Just remove `byebug gem` from your `Gemfile` then try to do `bundle install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Bundler 1.1` or later you can use `bundle clean`, or `bundle clean --force` just as you imagined you could. This is redundant if you're using `bundle install --path` (Bundler manages the location you specified with --path, so takes responsibility for removing outdated gems), but if you've used Bundler to install the gems as system gems then bundle clean --force will delete any system gems not required by your Gemfile. Blindingly obvious caveat: don't do this if you have other apps that rely on system gems that aren't in your Gemfile!

[Source -Bundle Clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905114/rails-bundle-clean)