# Error while running rails new App_Path or rails -- help -- Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting the same error message when I try to run `rails --help` and 'rails new APP_PATH. I have tried running `rvm gemset empty` and I keep getting the same error message. Do I have to uninstall Ruby and Rails and reinstall everything? I am worried about trying this solution but am tempted to try `bundle clean` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905114/rails-bundle-clean). Has anyone seen this error before and have any insight on how I may rectify it?

```
> rails --help
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
The most common rails commands are:
 generate     Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console      Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server       Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 test         Run tests except system tests (short-cut alias: "t")
 test:system  Run system tests
 dbconsole    Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
              (short-cut alias: "db")

 new          Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
              new application called MyApp in "./my_app"


All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
In addition to those commands, there are:

Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
    102: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    101: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    100: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
     99: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/bin/spring:15:in `require'
     98: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
     97: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
     96: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
     95: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     94: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     93: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
     92: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
     91: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
     90: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     89: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     88: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     87: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     86: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     85: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     84: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     83: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     82: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
     81: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
     80: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
     79: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
     78: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
     77: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     76: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/help/help_command.rb:11:in `help'
     75: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:86:in `print_commands'
     74: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:96:in `commands'
     73: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:96:in `flat_map'
     72: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:96:in `each'
     71: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:12:in `printing_commands'
     70: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:42:in `formatted_rake_tasks'
     69: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:33:in `rake_tasks'
     68: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
     67: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
     66: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     65: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     64: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     63: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     62: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     61: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     60: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     59: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     58: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
     57: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
     56: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
     55: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
     54: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
     53: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
     52: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     51: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     50: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     49: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     48: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     47: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     46: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sass-rails-6.0.0/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<main>'
     45: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     44: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     43: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     42: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     41: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     40: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     39: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     38: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     37: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails.rb:5:in `<main>'
     36: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     35: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     34: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     33: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     32: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     31: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     30: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     29: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     28: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sassc-2.3.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<main>'
     27: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
     26: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     25: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     24: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     23: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     22: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     21: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     20: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     19: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     18: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sassc-2.3.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:3:in `<main>'
     17: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     16: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     15: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     14: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     13: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     12: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     11: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     10: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
      9: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi.rb:4:in `<main>'
      8: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
      7: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
      6: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
      5: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:27:in `require'
      4: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:41:in `rescue in require'
      3: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
      2: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
      1: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
    102: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    101: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    100: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
     99: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/bin/spring:15:in `require'
     98: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
     97: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
     96: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
     95: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     94: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     93: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
     92: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
     91: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
     90: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     89: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     88: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     87: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     86: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     85: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     84: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     83: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     82: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
     81: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
     80: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
     79: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
     78: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
     77: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     76: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/help/help_command.rb:11:in `help'
     75: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:86:in `print_commands'
     74: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:96:in `commands'
     73: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:96:in `flat_map'
     72: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:96:in `each'
     71: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:12:in `printing_commands'
     70: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:42:in `formatted_rake_tasks'
     69: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:33:in `rake_tasks'
     68: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
     67: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
     66: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     65: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     64: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     63: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     62: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     61: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     60: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     59: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     58: from /Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/class/Labs/code-alongs/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
     57: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
     56: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
     55: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
     54: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
     53: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
     52: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     51: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     50: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     49: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     48: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     47: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     46: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sass-rails-6.0.0/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<main>'
     45: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     44: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     43: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     42: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     41: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     40: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     39: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     38: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     37: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails.rb:5:in `<main>'
     36: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     35: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     34: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     33: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     32: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     31: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     30: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     29: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     28: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sassc-2.3.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<main>'
     27: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
     26: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     25: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     24: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     23: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     22: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     21: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     20: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     19: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     18: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sassc-2.3.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:3:in `<main>'
     17: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     16: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     15: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     14: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     13: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     12: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     11: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     10: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
      9: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<main>'
      8: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <main>'
      7: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
      6: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
      5: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
      4: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
      3: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
      2: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
      1: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: 

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My rails version

```
> rails -v
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Rails 6.0.3.1
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Getting the same error

Comment: yes I had to change my ruby versions, try running ``rvm list`` then change the version by using rvm use ``2.3.6``. ( or whatever version is available)